# Error running Java program in Eclipse form Github

Tags: java, eclipse, git

So I am very new to using Github with Eclipse.  When I import a project into eclipse by using the HTTPS clone URL and try to run it, it gives me the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class UserEnviorment.Main
```

The project is stored in:

Macintosh HD > Users > Kyle > git

but the Eclipse workspace is somewhere else.  Would this cause problems?

Here is the class I am trying to run if that helps any

```
package UserEnviorment;

import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Does stuff until user exits program.
    }
}
```

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you are pretty new to Java as well. What command are you using to run the program? Which directory are you running it from?

Comment: A program from github is no different to any other one so the github is irrelevant here. When using Eclipse have you got programs running before,

Comment: Yes, If I copy any class from the Github project to a standard project in Eclipse, it runs just fine.  I am running it just by hitting the green "run" button in Eclipse.  The program above is not necessarily the one I am having trouble with, I just wrote it quickly to make sure the error was popping up for all classes in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I seem to have found a solution.  If I delete the project in Eclipse but don't remove the files from my hard drive, I can then create a new Java project in Eclipse and uncheck the box "use default location" and navigate to where the Github project is stored.